# Legend is not appending

Tags: json, svg, d3.js

I have draw two graph(Stacked Bar and Line ) on a single SVG. Both are appending properly. I need legend for both graphs on the same svg. Legends are coming for stacked bar graph not for the line graph. Code is bellow

```
var marginStackedLine = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 35},
    width = 690 - marginStackedLine.left - marginStackedLine.right,
    height = 230 - marginStackedLine.top - marginStackedLine.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .4);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#58585b","#00adef"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svgStackedLine = d3.select("#callVolume").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + marginStackedLine.left + marginStackedLine.right)
    .attr("height", height + marginStackedLine.top + marginStackedLine.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + marginStackedLine.left + "," + marginStackedLine.top + ")");

var x1 = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y1 = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x1)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y1)
    .orient("right")
    .tickFormat(d3.format("5"));

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x1(d.Days); })
    .y(function(d) { return y1(d.cost); });

   //Code For Stacked Bar Graph

d3.json("JSON/StackedLineBarData.json", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "key"; }));
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

  svgStackedLine.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svgStackedLine.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

  var state = svgStackedLine.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.key) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width",45)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

      //Legend for Stacked Bar Graph

   var legend = svgStackedLine.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + parseInt((i*100)-80)  + ",-18)"; });
   legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 103)
      .attr("y",0)
      .attr("width", 6)
      .attr("height", 6)
      .style("fill", color);

   legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 90)
      .attr("y", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("font","0.75em HelveticaNeue")
      .style("fill","#939597")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });


});

   //Code For Line graph On Stacked Bar graph

d3.json("JSON/StackedLineData.json", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.cost = +d.cost; 
  });

  x1.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Days; }));
  y1.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.cost; }));

  svgStackedLine.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis");

  svgStackedLine.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate("+ width +",0)")
      .call(yAxis1);

  svgStackedLine.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

      //Legend For Line Graph

  var legend1 = svgStackedLine.selectAll('.legend1')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 30) + ",20)")
        .data(status)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'legend1');

   legend1.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

    legend1.append('rect')
        .attr('x', width - 30)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', 10)
        .attr('height', 10);

    legend1.append('text')
        .attr('x', width - 8)
        .attr('y',0)
        .text(function(d){ return d.cost; });
});
```

Json objects are:

StackedLineBarData.json

```
[ { "key": "MON",

      "Call Conversion": 30,

      "Call Abaoundont": 40},

   {  "key": "TUE",

      "Call Conversion": 30,

      "Call Abaoundont": 30 },

  ]
```

StackedLineData.json

```
[

     {"Days":"1","cost":"10"},
    {"Days":"2","cost":"20"}

]
```

Comment: Please narrow it down to the relevant code instead of posting everything that you have. At first glance, I don't see any problem -- is it possible that the legend is appended, but appears outside of the SVG?

Comment: No legend is not appending. I have checked in firebug also that this is not appending.

Comment: What's `status` that you're passing in as data? It doesn't appear to be defined anywhere?

Comment: That is the mistake I have done. It should be Cost .data("Cost") Now its working properly.  Thanks Sir.

Comment: Great, I'll add this as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the legend for the line graph, you're calling `.data(status)`, where `status` isn't defined. If you pass in the right data there, it should work.